# Fine Zoom instructions (JQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox

I am currently trying to use the "Fine Zoom" jquery tool for handling pan and zoom on a website.  Here is the link to their instructions: http://codecanyon.net/item/fine-zoom/full_screen_preview/407907.  I followed their instructions, but for whatever reason I am receiving indicating that "fancybox" is not a function.

This is my call to fancybox:

```
$("a#lnkPan").fancybox({
    onComplete:function(){
        $('#imgPan').finezoom();
    }
});
```

I added their js libraries as well.  Has anyone been able to make "Fine Zoom" work?

Comment: Please learn how to post code in this forum.  Simply click the code format button `{}` above the editor.

Answer (score 0):

Fire up fiddler and take a look at the http traffic. My guess is your reference to the js file is 404'ing or erroring for some reason.

Comment: because I change the location of the demo

Comment: @albanx I suppose that would do it then.

Comment: no sorry, now it's ok, but stille the user there has not followed the install istructions

Answer (score 0):

I am the creator of finezoom. To use finezoom you just need to apply it to a image tag. In the web site I just only view an example how fine zoom can be used with fancybox that is another jQuery plugin. To use fine zoom just follow this steps:

- Load jQuery.js, finezoom.js and optionally jQueryMousewheel.js javascript files
- Prepare your image tag, give it and ID or CLASS
- Prepare your image tag
- Then call finezoom on the image class or id: `$('.class').finezoom();`

That's all, after this you can zoom in, out, drag, pan an image. If you need more instructions just contact me or visit again the documentation page, I just updated it.